# jQuery UI tooltips not closing divs on mouseout

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tooltip, jquery-ui-tooltip

## Problem

When I mouseover a jQuery tooltip, it keeps creating new child divs in an element called **`ui-helper-hidden-accessible`** which I've tried to close, but some of the divs are given a style of `display: none` and others actually appear at the bottom of the page.

- I'm currently using 1.12.1 of jQuery UI

### scripts.js

```
$(document).tooltip({
        tooltipClass: "popup",
        items: ".fa-question-circle",
        position: {
        my: "center bottom-15",
        at: "center top",
        collision: 'none',
        close: function(event, ui) {
            $(".ui-helper-hidden-accessible").remove();
        },
    },
    hide: false
});
```

### index.html

```
<p class="score__title">Student-teacher ratio <i class="fa fa-question-circle tooltip" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed aliquam gravida molestie. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nulla facilisi. Cras tempor nisi ac ligula molestie commodo. Sed varius magna at justo rutrum, et faucibus sapien cursus." aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
```

Comment: Can you add a jsFiddle recreating the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a few syntax errors in your code. After cleaning it up and testing it appears to work.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/17sj6Lj5/

**HTML**

```
<h1>
Widget
</h1>
<hr />
<div>
  <p class="score__title">Student-teacher ratio <i class="ui-icon ui-icon-help fa fa-question-circle tooltip" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed aliquam gravida molestie. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nulla facilisi. Cras tempor nisi ac ligula molestie commodo. Sed varius magna at justo rutrum, et faucibus sapien cursus."
    aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.fa-question-circle {
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.ui-icon {
  background-image: url(http://download.jqueryui.com/themeroller/images/ui-icons_ffffff_256x240.png)
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $(document).tooltip({
    tooltipClass: "popup",
    items: ".fa-question-circle",
    position: {
      my: "center bottom-15",
      at: "center top",
      collision: "none"
    },
    close: function(event, ui) {
      $(".ui-helper-hidden-accessible").remove();
    },
    hide: false
  });
});
```

You had not closed out the `position` properly. This means that `close` and `hide` was not being read.